# Bug on Kivy in Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

I made some code that runs ok on windows, mac and linux, but when I run it on Android it returns the wrong value in results. I couldn't find anything about this bug.

With these values: LPA = 0.79, VPA = 2.93, VAA = 19.53
VI must to be 7.22 and MS -63.05, but on android returns VI = 1 and MS = -94.88.

```
def ButAcao(self, obj):
      try:
          LPA = float(self.LPA.text)
          VPA = float(self.VPA.text)
          VAA = float(self.VAA.text)
          VIresultado = (22.5 * LPA * VPA)**(1 / 2)
          MSresultado = ((VIresultado / VAA) - 1) * 100
          VIresultado = str("{:.2f}".format(VIresultado))
          MSresultado = str("{:.2f}%".format(MSresultado))
          VIresultado = "Preço Justo por ação: " + VIresultado
          MSresultado = "Margem Segurança: " + MSresultado
      except:
          VIresultado = "erro"
          MSresultado = "erro"
          pass
      self.VI.text = VIresultado
      self.MS.text = MSresultado
      self.VI.texture_update()
      self.MS.texture_update()
```

Comment: Are you running under python3 on the desktop and python2 on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Check your emulator, or input calls/gets, or how you integrate it with Android. I executed your code with your described values and got what they should be:

```
VI = 7.22
MS = -63.05%
```

using [BlueStacks](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC6J2k8oTUAhVsz1QKHR8uAn0QFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluestacks.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGzERPRfPol143BYS4zPBXAVfKAhA) as the emulator and [QPython3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.qpython.qpy3&hl=en) as the IDE/terminal.

[image]

Comment: Yes on python that runs ok... but on android returns VI = 1 and MS = -94.88. I think that is a bug on kivy. I compile that on Buildozer to apk.

Comment: Then maybe try a different build agent, and if that still doesn't work, submit a bug to kivy. Other than that, we don't have enough to replicate your issue unless you give us more on how your code is implemented.

Comment: I resolve... Kivy on android uses python 2 and I have that operation (1/2) = 0 on python 2 on python 3 returns 0.5. Thank's...